# Create New Fields from List Values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of the form below which has two fields.  field1 is a categorical field with only two values TRUE or FALSE, and field2 is a list.  I would like to parse field2 and create new columns in my dataframe one for each unique value in the character list.  For example, I would like to create 3 new columns from the data below, the columns would be Bas, ants, and onal.  I would like the new columns to contain a flag TRUE or FALSE indicating that the field2 value for that row contained the value the field is named for.  For example, the row 1 value for the new column Bas would be TRUE, the row 1 value of column onal would be FALSE.  In Python there's a function called getdummies that does something similar.  I'm not sure if there's an equivalent in r, also I'm not exactly sure how to parse the list. Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Sample data:

```
structure(list(field1 = c("False", "TRUE"), field2 = list(
    c("Bas", "ants"), c("Bas", "onal"))), .Names = c("field1", 
"field2"), row.names = c(1904L, 1968L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is a sample of what I'd like the output to look like:

```
structure(list(field1 = c(FALSE, TRUE), field2 = list(
    c("Bas", "ants"), c("Bas", "onal")), class = "factor"), Bas = c(TRUE, TRUE
), ants = c(TRUE, FALSE), onal = c(FALSE, TRUE)), .Names = c("field1", 
"field2", "Bas", "ants", "onal"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Can you also show the expected output?

Comment: I added sample output.  Also I edited the sample data I posted originally.  I think I had one too many parenthesis in it.

Comment: The output is giving me errors. Can you check if there are some extra parentheses.  Also the Sample data is now a list.  The previous one was correct as it was a data.frame with list as a column.

Comment: I guess `library(qdapTools);!!(mtabulate(df1$field2))` would be the expected output.

Comment: I added the closing parentheses to the sample input data.  So now it's in the original form, thanks for the help.  Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mtabulate` from `library(qdapTools)`

```
library(qdapTools)
!!(mtabulate(df1$field2)) 
#      ants  Bas  onal
#[1,]  TRUE TRUE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE TRUE  TRUE
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(field1 = c("False", "TRUE"),
field2 = list(c("Bas", 
"ants"), c("Bas", "onal"))), .Names = c("field1", "field2"),
row.names = c(1904L, 1968L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
data<-structure(list(field1 = c("False", "TRUE"), field2 = c("Bas", "Bas"),field3=c("ants", "onal")), .Names = c("field1", 
"field2","field3"), row.names = c(1904L, 1968L), class = "data.frame")

library(reshape2)    
newdata <-melt(data,id.vars=c("field3","field2"))    
x<-acast(newdata, value~field3)    
y<-acast(newdata, value~field2)    
final=cbind(x,y)
```